# android can't see web service

Tags: javascript, android, wcf

I've written my first Android app (Sencha Touch + Phonegap using Eclipse on PC). It pulls some JSON from a WCF service. It works fine in the emulator.

I've now put it on my phone (Samsung GT-19100T running Gingerbread). The app runs but hangs when calling the service. The phone just shows the loading animation. The server shows no request has reached it. The phone can browse the net ok.

EDIT: I should add that the problem is not the server. I can browse to the same services ok on PC, and we have an iPhone app that works with it fine.

The only other strange thing I've noticed is that if I browse to the endpoint on iPhone or PC, I get the JSON text in the browser. If I try it on the android's browser it says "cannot download".

How do I go about diagnosing this?
Is there some sort of option on the phone?

Comment: if you are using localserver, then switch off the firewall (for windows O/S).

Comment: If you expose any web page on your server is it accessible from the mobile device? Is your server visible on to the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. The answer is to SHOOT ME NOW.

the URL had been entered so long ago I forgot all about it, including little details like the fact that it used an *internal ip address*.

Total facepalm. No, that won't do it. Let's try a facedesk...